# relation among views and models

Tags: java, model-view-controller

In the MVC pattern, if I have two different views, must I have two different models? Is there a one-to-one relationship between the view and the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MVC (Model View Controller) is a Design Pattern**, is based on the **principle of Do one thing and do it well...**

**A Single model can be used with N number of View...thats what the Specialty of MVC.**

**Model** contains the Business Logic and Data

**View** is what the used to display the result to the user.

**Controller** is the one on which the action is done

Swing in java is based on MVC. Also know as **PLAF** (Pluggable Look and Feel).

A Java program where Model is separate from the View, can easily be used with different View.

Eg:
    A Business Logic well written and separate from the View part, can be used in Swing as well as with JSP to show the Output...

Answer (score 5):

No, of course not. You might use the same model but have a view that displays a resume of the model, another that displays the full details of the model, and a third one which displays it in a form that is well-suited for smart phones.

That's one of the advantages and core principles of the MVC pattern: the controller builds the model, and delegates to the appropriate view to display the model.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not mandatory. A model can have one to many relationship with views.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single model and different views to present the model.

You may have a model class named **User** and a view to **list** the Users, another to **insert** a new user and another one to **update** a user.

Cheers!